# Problems in handling EntityFramework objects

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

(Using: Visual Studio 2010, SQL Server 2012, Entity Framework 4.0, MVC3 web application)

I have tables with one-to-many and many-to-many relationships, I used (database first) to automatically generate model classes, meaning I have objects inherited from `EntityObject` and the base class inherited from `ObjectContext`.

I am having trouble with (inserting, updating, deleting) objects.

For example when creating an object: I have a many-to-many relationship between 2 tables (`Area` and `Cell`) and the middle table (`CellArea`), and I want to add a new `Cell` object which is connected to many areas, so I did the following code:

```
Cell _cell = new Cell()

foreach (Area ar in current_areas)
{                    
    var ca = new CellArea();
    //ca attributes
    _cell.CellAreas.Add(ca);
}

db.SaveChanges();  

db.Cells.AddObject(_cell);

db.SaveChanges();
```

I tried other code snippets and none of them worked, I always get `IEntityChangeTracker` and other similar exceptions.

What is the proper way to manage such cases?

Comment: You need to include more information on the specific exceptions you are getting. IEntityChangeTracker is an interface, not an exception. If you want help you need to provide sufficient information so it is possible to determine what the problem is.

Comment: I am having many exceptions on different operations, so I think I am dealing with EF in the wrong way, in the example above when only one area added, I get "InvalidOperationException: An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."
exception on adding the _cell object.
when more than one area added I get also "InvalidOperationException: The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects." exception on the adding area line.

Answer (score 0):

When there are intertable relationships EF should create what is known as navigational properties.  When you perform the initial query you can either choose to have those properties loaded or not.  In particular EF has a keyword named Include that allows you to populate those other properties at will.  If all the other date is included and any changes are made, you only have to call the SaveChanges method and the original table data and all navigational property data is saved in one shot.

Google "EF Include"